# Compute the gradient of the SVM loss function

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, gradient

I am trying to implement the SVM loss function and its gradient.
I found some example projects that implement these two, but I could not figure out how they can use the loss function when computing the gradient.

Here is the formula of loss function:
[image]

What I cannot understand is that how can I use the loss function's result while computing gradient?

The example project computes the gradient as follows:

```
for i in xrange(num_train):
    scores = X[i].dot(W)
    correct_class_score = scores[y[i]]
    for j in xrange(num_classes):
      if j == y[i]:
        continue
      margin = scores[j] - correct_class_score + 1 # note delta = 1
      if margin > 0:
        loss += margin
        dW[:,j] += X[i]
        dW[:,y[i]] -= X[i]
```

dW is for gradient result. And X is the array of training data.
But I didn't understand how the derivative of the loss function results in this code.

Comment: What example are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method to calculate gradient in this case is Calculus (analytically, NOT numerically!). So we differentiate loss function with respect to W(yi) like this:
 [image]

and with respect to W(j) when j!=yi is:

[image]

The 1 is just indicator function so we can ignore the middle form when condition is true. And when you write in code, the example you provided is the answer.

Since you are using cs231n example, you should definitely check [note](http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-1/) and videos if needed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How did they develop these formulas from the basic SVM loss? Can you please explain in more detail? Thanks

Comment: @UriAbramson Hi! This is actually basic calculus. Differentiate (w(j).T * xi - w(yi).T * xi + delta) with respect to w(yi), we get -xi, and to differentiate with respect to w(j), we get xi (when the indicator function is true for both cases). Well, since the website doesn't support equation render, it is better to check [the original note](http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-1/), and if you have trouble understanding calculus, I recommend you watching khan academy. They have great tutorial videos. I hope this helps.

Comment: I understand it now. I didn't figure out that the 1(.... > 0) is a condition. Thanks for the explanation, can you please explain why you need to do 2 derivatives - one w.r.t Wj and the other w.r.t Wyi? How does it work..?

Comment: Wj and Wyi are different weight vectors, Wyi is the ideal weight vector and Wj I assume is the one we are trying to form

Comment: How come there is a summation when the gradient is in respect to Wyi but there is no summation when its in respect to Wj ? How does the summation just disappear.

Comment: I struggled to understand this. Fortunately, this one came to the rescue: https://mlxai.github.io/2017/01/06/vectorized-implementation-of-svm-loss-and-gradient-update.html

Comment: Shouldn't there be a summation term in both?

Answer (score 0):

If the substraction less than zero the loss is zero so the gradient of W is also zero. If the substarction larger than zero, then the gradient of W is the partial derviation of the loss.

Answer (score -2):

If we don't keep these two lines of code:

```
dW[:,j] += X[i]
dW[:,y[i]] -= X[i]
```

we get loss value.